# Edit the placeholder attribute with IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, placeholder

I'm trying to access and edit the placeholder attribute of an input field.

With IE8+ it's working. With IE7 it's not.

I can access and read the attribute, but I'm not able to edit the attribute with IE7.
I know the attribute is not working with IE9 and less but I'm using a plugin to make IE9 and less compatible.

```
//Console.log display the value on IE7
$item.attr('placeholder'); 

//Get an error on IE7, but works with IE8+. SCRIPT3: Member not found
$item.attr('placeholder', 'value');
```

Any idea to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: can you share the fiddle

Comment: Typically, you should use .prop() not .attr() but even im not sure its work on IE7 to change placeholder property which is not supported on this browser

Comment: have you considered simply dropping support for IE7? Especially for a non-critical feature like this -- the lack of a placeholder doesn't (or at least, it *shouldn't*) affect the direct usability of a site, so just leave it out and let IE7 users go without. It's not like there's a huge number of IE7 users out there anyway, and those that are using it will surely by now be well used to sites that don't look their best in their browser.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? is it http://widgetulous.com/placeholderjs/ by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a jQuery plugin to use placeholders. Several others plugins have the same issue, but [Daniel Stocks' one](https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/1085180) works for IE >= 7.

How to use it :

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Text field" />
<textarea placeholder="Text area"></textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();
```